# memcpy backtrace no symbols available

Tags: gdb, libc

I don't know why I can't see this backtrace. The symbols from my own binary are loaded, and the package `libc6-dbg` is installed. Do I need to tell gdb where to find the libc symbols?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memcpy_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../memcpy.S:74
74  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../memcpy.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt full
#0  __memcpy_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../memcpy.S:74
No locals.
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Is quite strange that you don't have a proper back trace, did you built with "-g -O0" options? Can it be a stack corruption that is overwriting return address?

Comment: @jcm would -O0 affect it?

Comment: Is possible that the builder is optimizing your application by trimming debug information from binary file. `-O0` disables optimization and avoid this possibility. On the other hand, from number of lines in the backtrace, I would bet for a stack corruption. I'll try to add an answer to try to help on this.

Answer (score 1):

From your backtrace, is possible that you've a stack corruption that is overwriting your return address (mainly because there's only two calls and no information about code calling memcpy is available). Is it possible that you're using `memcpy` over an address in the stack?

One way to check for this kind of corruptions is by using `watch` gdb command:

1. Most important part is delimit the call that should be corrupting. In your case should be a call to memcpy or close to it.
2. once you have a suspicious function, add a break point on it.
3. Run until break point is reached.
4. Set a watchpoint into calling function's address by: `watch 0xXXXXXX`
5. Run until watchpoint is reached.

If return address is overwritten, db should stop on corrupting call.